How to select floppy image in VICE 64 C64 Emulator
I just installed VICE64 on my Raspberry 4 running LibreElec.
VICE64 runs fine, but I cannot find out how to select a floppy image.
Why isn't such a central part of a program explained anywhere?
I was able to open the menu using some keystrokes on the keyboard — Enter, Esc, Alt… and Select X on the gamepad.
But in this menu there is no way to select an image. Or is there?

https://vice-emu.sourceforge.io/vice_1.html#SEC42

@ChanganAuto - I consider myself pretty bright and I have no idea what I am looking at that page, without reading several paragraphs of a manual, that I have no interest in. Care to explain?

@Ramhound That part of the manual is the one explaining how drive emulation works in VICE. There's a lot to it for sure because it can (and arguably must) emulate different generations of drives and not all work with all Commodore computers VICE64 is capable of emulating. Yes, it's very powerful and feature rich and because of that it takes time, dedication and patience to understand its ins and outs.

@ChanganAuto My question was not about how it works but on how you select an image from the emulator screen. Like how you open the menu. It does not make sense to go via command line on libreelec.

And that's why I pointed to the manual you must read and understand first. Comments aren't answers. You're under the impression it should be something as easy as adding an ISO to Virtualbox. It isn't.

@ChanganAuto Well, just proved you wrong: on PC it's File / Attach Disc image / drive 8 which opens a file open dialog.
